# SVN and TortoiseSVN access problems

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn

I have a user that can't access our internal svn/apache server from his winxp workstation. The problem occurs both in tortoiseSVN and the SVN CLI client. He is the only one, out of hundreds of users, with this problem.

There is no trace of his access attempts in the svn or apache logs and he get the error message back immediately.

He can access the server with his browser and telnet svn.company.com 80.

All proxy server settings are disabled in tsvn and in the cli svn settings.

I've tried to uninstall and reinstall both the CLI client (part of VisualSVN) and tortoiseSVN and remove all settings from %APPDATA%\Subversion and from the registry (both local machine and current user)

Here is the error message:

```
C:\>svn co http://svn.company.com/projects/myproj myproj
svn: OPTIONS of 'http://svn.company.com/projects/myproj': could not connect to server (http://svn.company.com)
```

Now to the funny part, if I add "--config-dir ." we get:

```
C:\>svn --config-dir . co http://svn.company.com/projects/myproj myproj
Authentication realm: <http://svn.company.com:80> SVN Server - projects
Password for 'user':
```

Any ideas on what I'm missing?

Comment: maybe, there's a subversion folder under AllUsers/ApplicationData?

Comment: @eckes, make that an answer and I'll check it! The user found this post, tried your solution and it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated by 8DH, I'm making my comment an answer:

Maybe, there's a subversion folder under `AllUsers/ApplicationData`? Using [Filemon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896642.aspx), I saw that `svn` also searches for settings in that directory...

Answer (score 1):

Its clear that you have some trace of svn settings still in the system.

Are you sure you do not have anything left in settings show in this [url](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-settings.html#tsvn-dug-settings-dia-4)

also check if there is any subversion folder in %HOMEPATH%